# Suppose that $x^2 = b$ where $x$ is an irrational positive real number and $b$ is an integer. Show that there exists a nontrivial unit in Z[x].

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Suppose that $Z[x]$ is composed of all numbers of the form $c + dx$ where $c$ and d are integers and $x$ is an irrational positive solution to the polynomial $x^2 + b = 0$ where $b$ is an integer.

> I seek to show that there exist any elements that are units aside from $1$ and $-1$. I know that these elements have norm $1$ or $-1$ and so $c^2 + bd^2 = 1$.

My trouble here is in determining the existence. I think it is a matter of supposing not and searching for a contradiction. In a somewhat non-concrete sense I was thinking that since this implies unequal elements with equal norms cannot divide each other then perhaps some kind of pigeonhole theorem argument comes into play. Perhaps it comes from showing an infinite number of any other integer occurs as the value of the norm?

Honestly, I have been stuck on this for a awhile. I know a norm of $-1$ directly implies the existence of an element with norm $1$. I'm just not sure how to find that one element.

This isn't an assignment or anything like that. I took a course on basic proofing that was number theory themed and well... I keep on trying to prove more things.

Edit: From the comments, it would appear this is equivalent to showing that for all b that are not perfect squares, Pell's Equation has a solution. Once again though, I'm looking for a simple proof. Even a link to a longer proof (if it is nontrivial) would be appreciated. Bonus points if this an unsolved conjecture. I love playing with those.

Edit2: [This article thing I found](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=20&ved=0ahUKEwiZj77e7ajVAhVKqVQKHf2OC2A4ChAWCF8wCQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oliforum.it%2Fdownload%2Ffile.php%3Fid%3D1105&usg=AFQjCNFFOWfQ67Oq7dUxrnJGH5f1w5n8QQ) seems to indicate the existence of solutions but I don't understand it at all. It seems to be drawing upon knowledge I don't understand yet.

Just to restate it with Pell's Equation:

> For all negative integers b such that b is not a square, does there exist a nontrivial solution to c^2 + bd^2 = 1?

Wikipedia's list of solutions seems to argue in favor of my conjecture, but I don't know for sure...

Comment: Down here you insist that $b$ must be positive.  So you should have put that in the wording of your question.  But if you did just that, with no other changes, then the question would make no sense.    When you say that x is "irrational positive", this implies that $b$ is negative -- if $b$ is positive, then $x^2 + b = 0$ has complex solutions, and complex numbers can be neither irrational nor positive.  This is why LordShark went ahead and assumed $b$ was negative -- you left the option open in the wording of your question, and it makes no sense as written if you demand $b$ is positive.

Comment: Typhon, the title of the question is most confusing: There you say that $x^2=b$ is irrational and positive. You're referring to $x$, not to $x^2$.

Comment: Theorem 7 of http://math.uga.edu/~pete/4400pellnotes.pdf proves it with a pretty minimal amount of work.  The first person to give a modern proof was Lagrange, using continued fractions.  But the first people to effectively solve the problem were ancient Indian mathematicians Jayadeva (9th century) and Bhaskara II (11th century), with an algorithm called Chakravala.  IMO this is the most stunning achievement in number theory before Fermat.  It is too much to hope for a very simple proof, as even for small b, the smallest solution can still be very large, e.g., b=-61, x=1766319049, y=226153980

Comment: P.S., there is still the sign issue in your final boxed statement.    It should say "for all negative integers b such that $|b|$ is not a square...", or even better, replace $b$ with $-b$ to simplify the statement.

Comment: No.  But I do recommend learning one of the algorithms to compute solutions and trying to compute some "large" solutions with them.  I personally like using binary quadratic forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of the Pell $x^2-dy^2=1$ equation are connected to the continued fraction expansion of $\sqrt{d}$.
By Lagranges Theorem 
( http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangesContinuedFractionTheorem.html )
$\sqrt{d}$ has a regular continued fraction which is periodic after some point.
For a proof of this theorem see ( 
http://wstein.org/edu/124/lectures/lecture19/lecture19/node2.html ). 
The connection between solutions of Pell equation and continued fractions is given here (
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.604.174&rep=rep1&type=pdf )

**Theorem 2.6.** Let variables be as defined in the previous theorem. Let $l$ be the minimal period of the continued fraction of $\sqrt{d}$.

(a) The minimal solution to Pell’s
equation is:
$(x_1,y_1) =$ 
$(p_{l−1}, q_{l−1}) \text{ if l is even },
(p_{2l−1}, q_{2l−1}) \text{ if l is odd }$

By Lagranges Theorem such $l$ always exists, hence there is always a nontrivial solution to Pell's equation.